# Wicket - cant run Library Application example

Tags: java, wicket

I am trying to run an example "[Library Application](https://github.com/apache/wicket/tree/master/wicket-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/examples/library)" from the Wicket Examples  page  and I have copied all the necessary classes/html files on my eclipse project.

The problem is that I can't run the application due to the following error:

> Unexpected RuntimeException Last cause:
>   org.apache.wicket.AttributeModifier.(Ljava/lang/String;ZLorg/apache/wicket/model/IModel;)V
>   WicketMessage: Can't instantiate page using constructor 'public
>   com.interamerican.SignIn()'. An exception has been thrown during
>   construction!
>
> Stacktrace Root cause:
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.wicket.AttributeModifier.(Ljava/lang/String;ZLorg/apache/wicket/model/IModel;)V
>        at org.apache.wicket.devutils.debugbar.DebugBar.(DebugBar.java:72)
>        at com.interamerican.WicketExampleHeader.(WicketExampleHeader.java:33)
>        at com.interamerican.WicketExamplePage.buildHeader(WicketExamplePage.java:57)
>        at com.interamerican.WicketExamplePage.(WicketExamplePage.java:47)
>        at com.interamerican.SignIn.(SignIn.java:27)
>        at com.interamerican.SignIn.(SignIn.java:17)
>        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>        at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:175)
>        at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:67)
>        at org.apache.wicket.DefaultMapperContext.newPageInstance(DefaultMapperContext.java:90)
>        at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider$Provision.getPage(PageProvider.java:380)
>        at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:171)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.PageRenderer.getPage(PageRenderer.java:78)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.renderPage(WebPageRenderer.java:102)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:195)
>        at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:202)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:912)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerExecutor.execute(RequestHandlerExecutor.java:65)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:283)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:253)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:221)
>        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:262)
>        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:204)
>        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:286)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1340)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1242)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:503)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:411)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:305)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:159)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
>        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
>        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Complete stack:
>
> org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using
>   constructor 'public com.interamerican.SignIn()'. An exception has been
>   thrown during construction!
>        at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:194)
>        at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:67)
>        at org.apache.wicket.DefaultMapperContext.newPageInstance(DefaultMapperContext.java:90)
>        at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider$Provision.getPage(PageProvider.java:380)
>        at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:171)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.PageRenderer.getPage(PageRenderer.java:78)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.renderPage(WebPageRenderer.java:102)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:195)
>        at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:202)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:912)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerExecutor.execute(RequestHandlerExecutor.java:65)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:283)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:253)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:221)
>        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:262)
>
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>        at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:175)
>        at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:67)
>        at org.apache.wicket.DefaultMapperContext.newPageInstance(DefaultMapperContext.java:90)
>        at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider$Provision.getPage(PageProvider.java:380)
>        at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:171)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.PageRenderer.getPage(PageRenderer.java:78)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.renderPage(WebPageRenderer.java:102)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:195)
>        at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:202)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:912)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerExecutor.execute(RequestHandlerExecutor.java:65)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:283)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:253)
>        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:221)
>        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:262)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use the same version of Wicket for all modules - wicket-core, wicket-devutils, wicket-util, wicket-request and any others you may use.

Also use some new version like 8.2.0 or 7.10.0. From the package names I have the feeling that you use something older than 6.0.